# How are parameters passed from SQL Server to a CLR based stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssms, sqlclr

Using this example:

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynsearch-2008/search_orders_cs.cs

....I built and successfully deployed a CLR based stored procedure to SQL Server.  When viewing the resulting stored procedure definition within SSMS (see code below), I notice that the parameters as defined in the C# definition are indeed part of the SP definition, but when you look at the actual call to the stored procedure, there is no reference to the parameters, so I'm curious how the parameter values are actually passed through?

(The reason I ask specifically is, in the c# code, I'm wondering if I could set the **Query** variable to any existing stored procedure I want, and then in one big varchar argument pass in **all** the relevant arguments as delimited KeyValue pairs, and then split those and add them as Command.Parameters within a loop.  Basically, I'm trying to build a generic stored procedure that can execute any other stored procedure, without any restrictions on varying count or data types of parameters, all of that would be read at runtime.  So basically, the same flexibility you have when calling from C# into SQL Server, except implemented in SQL Server.)

Resulting Stored Proc (viewed within SSMS):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[search_orders_cs]
    @Orderid [int],
    @Fromdate [datetime],
    @Todate [datetime],
    @Minprice [money],
    @Maxprice [money],
    @Custid [nvarchar](4000),
    @Custname [nvarchar](4000),
    @City [nvarchar](4000),
    @Region [nvarchar](4000),
    @Country [nvarchar](4000),
    @Prodid [int],
    @Prodname [nvarchar](4000),
    @Debug [bit]
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
EXTERNAL NAME [SqlServerProject1].[StoredProcedures].[search_orders_cs]
GO


EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'SqlAssemblyFile', @value=N'twg_clr_based_sp.cs' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'PROCEDURE',@level1name=N'search_orders_cs'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'SqlAssemblyFileLine', @value=N'23' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'PROCEDURE',@level1name=N'search_orders_cs'
GO
```

C# Source:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void search_orders_cs(
           SqlInt32 Orderid,
           SqlDateTime Fromdate,
           SqlDateTime Todate,
           SqlMoney Minprice,
           SqlMoney Maxprice,
           SqlString Custid,
           SqlString Custname,
           SqlString City,
           SqlString Region,
           SqlString Country,
           SqlInt32 Prodid,
           SqlString Prodname,
           SqlBoolean Debug)
    {
        string Query;
        SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand();

        Query = @"SELECT o.OrderID, o.OrderDate, od.UnitPrice, od.Quantity,
                     c.CustomerID, c.CompanyName, c.Address, c.City,
                     c.Region, c.PostalCode, c.Country, c.Phone,
                     p.ProductID, p.ProductName, p.UnitsInStock,
                     p.UnitsOnOrder
              FROM   dbo.Orders o
              JOIN   dbo.[Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
              JOIN   dbo.Customers c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
              JOIN   dbo.Products p ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
              WHERE  1 = 1 ";

        if (!Orderid.IsNull)
        {
            Query += " AND o.OrderID = @orderid " +
                     " AND od.OrderID = @orderid";
            Command.Parameters.Add("@orderid", SqlDbType.Int);
            Command.Parameters["@orderid"].Value = Orderid;
            Command.Parameters["@orderid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        }

        if (!Fromdate.IsNull)
        {
            Query += " AND o.OrderDate >= @fromdate";
            Command.Parameters.Add("@fromdate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            Command.Parameters["@fromdate"].Value = Fromdate;
            Command.Parameters["@fromdate"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        }

        if (!Todate.IsNull)
        {
            Query += " AND o.OrderDate <= @todate";
            Command.Parameters.Add("@todate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            Command.Parameters["@todate"].Value = Todate;
            Command.Parameters["@todate"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        }

        if (!Minprice.IsNull)
        {
            Query += " AND od.UnitPrice >= @minprice";
            Command.Parameters.Add("@minprice", SqlDbType.Money);
            Command.Parameters["@minprice"].Value = Minprice;
            Command.Parameters["@minprice"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        }

        if (!Maxprice.IsNull)
        {
            Query += " AND od.UnitPrice <= @maxprice";
            Command.Parameters.Add("@maxprice", SqlDbType.Money);
            Command.Parameters["@maxprice"].Value = Maxprice;
            Command.Parameters["@maxprice"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        }

        if (!Custid.IsNull)
        {
            Query += " AND o.CustomerID = @custid" +
                     " AND c.CustomerID = @custid";
            Command.Parameters.Add("@custid", SqlDbType.NChar, 5);
            Command.Parameters["@custid"].Value = Custid;
            Command.Parameters["@custid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        }

        if (!Custname.IsNull)
        {
            Query += " AND c.CompanyName LIKE @custname + '%'";
            Command.Parameters.Add("@custname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40);
            Command.Parameters["@custname"].Value = Custname;
            Command.Parameters["@custname"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        }

        if (!City.IsNull)
        {
            Query += " AND c.City = @city";
            Command.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15);
            Command.Parameters["@city"].Value = City;
            Command.Parameters["@city"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        }

        if (!Region.IsNull)
        {
            Query += " AND c.Region = @region";
            Command.Parameters.Add("@region", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15);
            Command.Parameters["@region"].Value = Region;
            Command.Parameters["@region"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        }

        if (!Country.IsNull)
        {
            Query += " AND c.Country = @country";
            Command.Parameters.Add("@country", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15);
            Command.Parameters["@country"].Value = Country;
            Command.Parameters["@country"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        }

        if (!Prodid.IsNull)
        {
            Query += " AND od.ProductID = @prodid" +
                     " AND p.ProductID = @prodid";
            Command.Parameters.Add("@prodid", SqlDbType.Int);
            Command.Parameters["@prodid"].Value = Prodid;
            Command.Parameters["@prodid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        }

        if (!Prodname.IsNull)
        {
            Query += " AND p.ProductName LIKE @prodname + '%'";
            Command.Parameters.Add("@prodname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40);
            Command.Parameters["@prodname"].Value = Prodname;
            Command.Parameters["@prodname"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        }

        Query += " ORDER BY o.OrderID";

        using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
        {
            Connection.Open();

            if (Debug)
            {
                SqlContext.Pipe.Send(Query);
            }

            Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            Command.CommandText = Query;
            Command.Connection = Connection;
            SqlContext.Pipe.ExecuteAndSend(Command);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Did u ever settle on a solution. I am using a generic clr to do an insert exec stored proc, and I was trying to settle on a generic list of parameters that I could loop over as well when executing the stored proc name that I passed in

Comment: Sorry I have not, I don't think I even got to testing this approach, although it seems almost certain that it does work, I was jut curious HOW it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there is no reference to the parameters, so I'm curious how the parameter values are actually passed through?

It is the same signature (datatype & position only) between the T-SQL wrapper object (i.e. the Stored Procedure, Function, User-Defined Type, User-Defined Aggregate, or Trigger) that you see in SQL Server and interact with via T-SQL (e.g. the `CREATE PROCEDURE` example in the question) and the .NET method that is referenced via the `EXTERNAL NAME` clause of that T-SQL wrapper object.

The parameter names are not matched between the T-SQL wrapper object parameters and the .NET method's parameters. You can verify this by rearranging the parameter names in the Stored Procedure shown in the question, or even just rename them all to be `@a`, `@b`, '@c', etc. Then change the `CREATE` into `ALTER`, run it, and then run the Stored Procedure again with the same inputs and it will still work just as it did before the parameter names change.

---

On a related note, that particular usage of SQLCLR is fairly pointless. It offers no benefit over doing the same thing in pure T-SQL (i.e. dynamically creating a query, list of parameters, and list of parameter values, in 3 NVARCHAR(MAX) variables, and then combining them in a second dynamically created query that is just the `EXEC sp_executesql` call. Now, if that dynamic search proc would have instead been a TVF, *that* would be a valid use of SQLCLR as it would be doing something that cannot be done in T-SQL: dynamic SQL in a function!

Comment: Dynamic SQL in a TVF sounds interesting indeed, defintely something to investigate.  So I tried tackling this remote SP call with dynamic SQL today with SQL CLR using integrated auth and immediately ran into this issue: Kerberos Protocol Transition and Constrained Delegation.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345135%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: @tbone Yes, that is an issue with this whether you use Impersonation or not. The old Kerberos double-hop limitation. Now, if the process is automated via SQL Agent, then the login is directly to the SQL Server machine so you shouldn't have the Kerberos issue. Or if you don't use Impersonation and instead let the process use the security context of the MSSQLSERVER service account, that should also work. But this is for a different question, right? Enabling Delegation will also fix that issue. I link to an article that shows how to set that up in one of the Stairway to SQLCLR articles.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example that you can use to call a method in DLL.

> **Step 1.** Create a library class in Visual Studio

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class MyClass
    {
        [SqlProcedure]
        public static void MyMethod(SqlString strInParam, out SqlString strOutParam)
        {
            strOutParam = $"Hi '{strInParam}', The date time is: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        }
    }
}
```

> **Step 2.** Create an assembly

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [AssemblyName]
    AUTHORIZATION dbo
    FROM 'DLL_Path'
    WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
GO
```

> **Step 3.** Create a procedure

```
-- DROP PROCEDURE MyProcedure
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure(@strInParam nvarchar(1000), @strOutParam nvarchar(1000) OUTPUT)
    AS EXTERNAL NAME [AssemblyName].[MyNamespace.MyClass].[MyMethod]
GO
```

> **Step 4.** Enable CLR

```
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled'
GO
```

> **Step 5.** Executing the stored-procedure will result in callling the
>   written method

```
DECLARE @res NVARCHAR(1000);
EXEC dbo.MyProcedure @strInParam = 'Siya', @strOutParam = @res OUTPUT;

SELECT @res
```

> **The result is:**
>   
>   Hi 'Siya', The date time is: 2018/05/19 14:17:47